# How to save plot with its colourbar as .fig in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a button which will produce plot along with its color bar by clicking on it. The button relates to certain function called zzpcolor. Inside zzpcolor, I use pcolor syntax to produce shake map.

Inside the callback function, I use hold on to hold the figure generated by zzpcolor. Then I add another plot to the same axis. This is part of the script within the push botton callback.

```
axes(handles.axes1);
axes1.Position=[0.1300 0.1100 0.7750 0.8150];
[X,Y,Z]=plotpcolor(fnamedat);
hold on
zzpcolor(X,Y,Z);
shading flat
LimitPlot
hold on
plot_google_map
hold on
scatter(datageo(:,1),datageo(:,2),'MarkerFaceColor',[1 0 0])
hold off
```

The syntax worked just fine. I use this syntax to save the plot as jpg in another callback function.

```
newfig1 = figure('Visible','off'); 
copyobj(handles.axes1, newfig1);
[filename,pathname]= uiputfile('*.jpg','Save as'); 
hold on
wmmicolorbarsetting;
saveas(newfig1,[pathname,filename],'jpg');
```

it works just fine. But when I try to save it as .fig using similar syntax like this,

```
newfig1 = figure('Visible','off'); 
copyobj(handles.axes1, newfig1);
[filename,pathname]= uiputfile('*.fig','Save as'); 
hold on
wmmicolorbarsetting;
saveas(newfig1,[pathname,filename],'fig');
```

the .fig file contains nothing. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .fig file *does* contain something. You set the figure `Visible` property to `'off'` so the figure doesn't actually show up when you create the figure **or** when you load the figure from the file.

You can verify this by loading the .fig file with `hgload` and setting the `Visible` property to `'on'`.

```
fig = hgload([pathname, filename]);
set(fig, 'Visible', 'on')
```

You can also look at the produced .fig file and ensure that it is non-empty.

You can fix this by setting `Visible` to `'on'` prior to saving.

**A note on figure visibility:** Setting `Visible` to `'off'` is useful for saving a figure as a format other than .fig (png, jpeg, etc.) because you can create an image without worrying about a bunch of figures showing up  as your script runs. In these cases, no user interaction is required. As you've found out, if you actually need to see/interact with figures, `Visible` should be `'on'` to be useful.